# How to create below type html window?

Tags: html, css

I have to create below type html page. background (orange) image.

HTML gurus, Please help out.!

[image]

Comment: try rephrasing your question and giving more detail... i have no idea what youre trying to do by the screenshot you posted and your limited description.

Comment: Are you trying to poistion a window "below" another, or have one overlaying? Your question is very confusing

Comment: I want create same type of html page. I can not see HTML view source.

Comment: I think he just wants somebody to code up the HTML required to create the contents of the window, nothing to do with displaying/positioning a popup via JS.

Comment: Open the page in Firefox, right-click, "view page source". As far as the orange background, it's just a background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="top_container">
  <!--Put the background image in this div.-->
  </div>
  <div id="bottom_container">
  <!--Input stuff-->
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish in recreating the image? Are you trying to add specific functionality to your website? Please be specific. If you are just trying to recreate the look of that website, you could easily just View Source to see for yourself.

In the meantime, I highly suggest reading through the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) tutorials on HTML and CSS. It will explain everything you need to know about creating your own web forms, background colors, and so on.